# How does the plot progress in Shadowrun: Hong Kong?

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

So, it's day two of my shadowrunnig career, first mission done, jobs are piling up fast. That got me thinking. I'm a completionist, and would like to (at least) have an opportunity of taking every side mission I'll want to take.

Is that possible? Do I have a limited amount of missions before the plot progresses? Does sleeping in the bunk affect that? How to tell which actions move the plot forward and which are non-essential?

Answer (score 3):

So, after doing the work myself:

Every mission gained through the computer could be considered a side mission. The plot moves forward after each mission (regardless of sleeping), along with dialogues etc. After set amount of missions you get the info about starting the endgame, getting explicit warning that after taking that route coming back to various shadowruns will not be possible. As far as I could tell, despite of what the briefings might tell you, no side mission is time-dependant and all of them can be completed before moving on.

Comment: I'm not convinced there are no time-dependent missions. For example, I had one mission from Kinley's "assistant" (forgot his name) which I delayed for a few missions, and then I got an angry email that he "took care of it  himself" and he won't forget this.